Next.js load video remotely from Instagram
I'm attempting to load a video remotely from Instagrams servers into my Next.js app and play it.
I'm being met with a 403 Forbidden.
Instagram is giving this URL to access the video:
https://scontent-syd2-1.cdninstagram.com

I'm doing a very basic JSX output like so:
<video src={MY_INSTA_URL} type="video/mp4"></video>

Is there any way I can update the next.config.js to allow videos from this address?
---UPDATE---
I should mention that I have successfully loaded images from Instagram by adding this snippet to my next.config.js
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "scontent-syd2-1.cdninstagram.com",
        port: "",
        pathname: "/**",
      },
    ],
  },
};

So it's just a video issue now.
